# Remove entity without loading first in Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am wanting to remove an entity from a database using LINQ2SQL without having to pre-fetch it (for performance reasons).

I undersand that this can be done as follows([Delete a LINQ to SQL record without loading it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312201/delete-a-linq-to-sql-record-without-loading-it-first) ):

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
    var e = new TestEntity { Id = id };

    _context.TestEntities.Attach(e, false);
    _context.TestEntities.DeleteOnSubmit(e);
}
```

however when TestEntity contains a datetime similar to:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String TestString { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public int TestInt { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

which basically means its trying to validate .net default datetime against a SQL datetime

Is there a way of deleting an entity with a non-nullable without needing to prefetch it?

*Note ive also tried setting the datetime value to a dummy one, in which case i get the following:

> Row not found or changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Row not found or changed" suggests that you have those columns set for validation. If you have a timestamp (`rowversion`) column, you could use that single value for optimistic concurrency checks, although you still won't know the value, of course. In some cases, you could disable concurrency checks *completely* (set `UpdateCheck="Never"` on all the interesting columns in the dbml).

However, perhaps a simpler option is:

```
_context.ExecuteCommand("delete from [TableName] where [PrimaryKey]={0}", id);
```

or something along those lines. Not object oriented, but very effective. Note that this doesn't run in the same transaction as `SubmitChanges` unless you manage the transaction yourself, and that it won't validate that exactly 1 row was deleted. But it is direct. Also note that the data-context won't know about this change, so if your data-context also has (say) pending updates for that row it could get confused.

Comment: @Luke beware: that will mean you don't get concurrency checks on your updates, too.

Comment: that should be fine I'm actually only using it for a performance test anyway and validating state aftewards

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
```

to

```
public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }
```

And set this field NULLable in your database table

Comment: I want to do this without setting this as nullable. I shouldnt have to change my model to make it fast to delete

Comment: OK, you haven't noticed about that. What about changing default value of the field in datamodel or orm layer?