# Select before delete? Or just delete? What is faster in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm

I was wondering, I have a sequence of two methods in an ORM in c#, one checks that there is something to delete before sending a delete statement, but I was wondering, is it faster to just try and delete given that if it fails I will only get an error?

What I want to know is that if the select statement is faster than just sending a delete that would raise an error.

Ideas?

Comment: Is this an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312201/delete-a-linq-to-sql-record-without-loading-it-first

Comment: That is a way to delete entities fooling the ORM into thinking the entity was loaded, I am already applying something similar, but just for the sake of protective programming I would want to check if the entity exists in the database before the delete satement.

Comment: Why do you think that a delete that affects no rows will raise an error?